# Converting Word document to PDF fomat in the cloud

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2012, ms-word

Hi and thanks in advance.

I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2013 in this project. My task is to find a way to convert Word documents to .pdf and the conversion needs to be done in the cloud. Any suggestions?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: I think this is too broad a question, inviting too much in the way of opinion and not enough in the way of quantifiable answers. There are a great many ways to achieve what you're looking for, and most of them will start with some light Googling.

Comment: I have googled this which is why I'm here... 
I do want others opinion on this.

Comment: Excellent! Which is your favoured approach, and what problem is it you're having with it?

Comment: I guess I wasn't to good at specifics so here they are:
I need a way to access an application in the cloud that will convert a Word document to .pdf document. 
I need to access this application from within C# code (MVC platform).
Thanks!

Comment: As per the original comment, you'll find a bunch of web based services if you search the web, typically priced in cents per conversion.  Out of interest, why do you require a cloud service, as opposed to something local to your application?

Answer (score 1):

You may get different results from different service providers. Since you have a MVC application, I would consider having a server-side conversion service instead of a cloud one, because you could achieve better performance.

Conversion service could be template based with OpenXML API support, so that no Word instance is needed on the server. One tool that I think of could be suitable for you is [Docentric Toolkit](http://www.docentric.com). You have to buy a license, though. So if you have budget for it, this might work for you. Beside .docx you can get pdf or xps output.

Answer (score 1):

Number of cloud solutions are available for DOCX to PDF conversion. I suggest  [GroupDocs.Conversion Cloud Service](https://github.com/groupdocs-conversion-cloud/groupdocs-conversion-cloud-dotnet) for high quality and reliable PDF conversion, it supports 50+ popular file formats.